# How do I check if a URL will download a file using Selenium in Python?

Tags: python, selenium, url

I have to visit a list of URLs but I do not want to open those which will start a download.

```
for url in url_list:
   if (url will not start a download):
      driver.get(url)
      ..................
   else:
      continue
```

Does someone have a solution for this? thanks in advance for the answers

Comment: What conditions have you tried? Have you seen any difference between a regular URL an a URL that will start a download? Maybe the one that triggers a download will contain the extension of the file and you can check if some extensions like .pdf, .mp4 are in the URL or maybe you can check with a regular expression. Try some things, add the code here + URL samples.

Comment: Checking the URLs is indeed a very nice option, I have implemented it and reduced the problem a little bit, however I still have problems when a redirection is involved, do you have any alternative for that?

Comment: Please update your question with details of what happens, and see if is anything specific in the case, maybe the url contains a specific string.

Answer (score 2):

first you can get url then in java with selenium you can below condition in if:

```
(String)((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return document.contentType;").equals("text/html");
```

Comment: The question is about how to do it in Python.

Comment: it must have similar solution in python. I found that and edit it.